# How is memory managed with &str and String, native types and PyResult<T> when passing values from Rust to Python?

Tags: rust, pyo3

Using PyO3, I am able to pass `&str` and `String` types from Rust to Python:

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn test_str(py: Python) -> &str {
    "this is a &str"
}

#[pyfunction]
fn test_string(py: Python) -> String {
    "this is a String".to_string()
}
```

And Python is able to call these fine:

```
>>> test_str(), type(test_str())
('this is a &str', <class 'str'>)
>>> test_string(), type(test_string())
('this is a String', <class 'str'>)
```

I am also able to wrap these as `PyResult<&str>` and `PyResult<String>` with the same behavior.

What, if anything, do I need to know and other steps do I need to take to make sure the memory is handled properly here? If I'm not trying to maintain references to the same strings, do I need to tell the GIL about the `String`s so it can free them when necessary?

If I need to do more, do I also need to do the same for other methods, such as when I create a Rust `struct`?

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn new_thing(py: Python) -> Thing {
    Thing { foo: 1, bar: true }
}
```